# Unauthorized problem with impersonating an user

Tags: impersonation, runwithelevatedprivileges

I'm trying to get this result: i want me to impersonate an user X, write down a file in a List (in which X has contribute rights), and change the privileges so that noone else can modify that..

So i decide..

```
1. Elevate Privilage
2. Open SC as User (by Token)
3. Add item
4. Add User as Contributor
5. Remove the group of User from the Contribution
```

Is there something wrong?

Here's my code:

```
 string fullsite = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/sites/ReplyCorp";
 SPUserToken myToken = TokenManager.GetToken(addContentObj.userId);

 Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
 {
      using (SPSite scSite = new SPSite(fullsite, myToken))
      {
             using (SPWeb scWebAllReplyers = scSite.OpenWeb("AllReplyers"))
             {
                   scWebAllReplyers.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                   scWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                   SPList listContenuti = scWebAllReplyers.Lists["Contenuti"];
                   SPListItem nuovoElemento = listContenuti.AddItem();
                   nuovoElemento["Title"] = addContentObj.contentTitle;
                   nuovoElemento.Update();

                   var allreplyers = scWebAllReplyers.Groups["AllReplyers"];
                   AssignPermissionsToItem(nuovoElemento, (SPPrincipal)scWebAllReplyers.AllUsers[addContentObj.userId], SPRoleType.Contributor);
                   AssignPermissionsToItem(nuovoElemento, (SPPrincipal)allreplyers, SPRoleType.Readern);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }


public static void AssignPermissionsToItem(SPListItem item, SPPrincipal obj, SPRoleType roleType)
    {
        if (!item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
        {
            item.BreakRoleInheritance(false, true);
            item.Update();
        }
        SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(obj);
        SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = item.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(roleType);

        roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);

        item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
    }
```

The problem I get is "Unauthorized User", even if my user is Admin and the other user is contributor and owner of the file (running withelevated Privileges!)

Thank you very much!

Comment: What for a TokenManager class? Is it custom implementation?

Comment: Yess, and works! Tested and used many times!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just understand WHY it wont work... I was impersonating the user, so the "ElevatedPrivileges" where "capped" by the impersonated "roles"... I split the code in two parts: first of all, impersonating, I create the item, and then, creating another SPWeb i connect as Admin and change the privileges on that item!

```
            string fullsite = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/sites/ReplyCorp";
            SPUserToken myToken = TokenManager.GetToken(addContentObj.userId);

            Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite scSite = new SPSite(fullsite, myToken))
                {
                    using (SPWeb webRoot = scSite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                      using (SPWeb webAllReplyers = scSite.OpenWeb("AllReplyers"))
                            {
                                webAllReplyers.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                scSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                                SPList listContenuti = webAllReplyers.Lists["Contenuti"];
                                SPListItem nuovoElemento = listContenuti.AddItem();
                                nuovoElemento["Title"] = addContentObj.contentTitle;
                                nuovoElemento.Update();

                                DEBUG = nuovoElemento.UniqueId;
                                Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                                {
                                    using (SPSite SiteColl = new SPSite(fullsite))
                                    {
                                        using (SPWeb scWebElevated = SiteColl.OpenWeb("AllReplyers"))
                                        {
                                            scWebElevated.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                            scSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                                            SPList listaContenuti = scWebElevated.Lists["Contenuti"];
                                            SPListItem item = listaContenuti.Items[DEBUG];
                                            item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                                            item.Update();

                                            scWebElevated.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                                            var allreplyers = scWebElevated.Groups["AllReplyers"];
                                            AssignPermissionToItem(item, (SPPrincipal)scWebElevated.AllUsers[addContentObj.userId], SPRoleType.Contributor, scWebElevated);
                                            AssignPermissionToItem(item, (SPPrincipal)allreplyers, SPRoleType.Reader, scWebElevated);
                                        }
                                    }

                                });
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: As always in these scenarios - consider NOT using RWEP but instead just open the SPSite object using the system token? You really don't need to impersonate here.